# Merge existing data with iCloud using MagicalRecord

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, icloud, magicalrecord

I have an iOS 7 app in production that uses MagicalRecord for handling coreData. Right now I use `[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:@"Name.sqlite"];` to setup the stack.

I wanted to include iCloud for my app as well and by using `[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithiCloudContainer:@"XXXXXXXX.com.sample.AppName" localStoreNamed:@"Name.sqlite"];` I can successfully sync data on multiple devices.

This is causing a problem though. The data that is stored in Name.sqlite doesn't sync with iCloud and it creates a new set of data for the sync. So if I had 15 records previously, once I turn iCloud on, it shows 0 records. If I turn iCloud off, it goes back to 15 records.

My question is, how do I merge those 15 records to iCloud when it's turned on? Can't really find any documentation on it or any methods that'll help out.

Comment: You would need explicitly migrate the data from your local store to the iCloud store when you turn on iCloud. I'm not sure if MagicalRecord can do that for you, or if you have to set it up yourself somehow.

Comment: @DrewMcCormack I tried adding in the sqlite with records on to the stack but then it just creates multiple duplicates on the device. It syncs it to device B perfectly but then sync from device A to B stops. Sync from device B to A works fine. It's so confusing.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid it is confusing. It may be worth looking at a non-Apple solution. I develop the ensembles framework (ensembles.io) which automatically imports local data, and deduplicates if you provide global ids.

Comment: @AmitWadhawan did you ever get this to work correctly?

Comment: @spokane-dude Yes and No. It does work but I was having issues with providing users with an on and off switch. It may have improved with recent updates.